# Hooking up a domain to Apache

Tags: server, apache2, dns

I've downloaded Apache on an external Ubuntu machine, made a website and now I want to make it public. I've bought a domain (DNS) at godaddy.com and made an A-record to my server's ip, (which is the same as my other pc's ip, not the 192.168... ip) and port-forwarded 80 and 443 . I have edited the etc/hosts and made Virtual Hosts. Doing all of this didn't work. Also I have followed just about every guide and videos on the internet and frankly I am beginning to give up.

I hope some of you could assist me in this.

Comment: Is this on GoDaddy?

Comment: What happens when you ping the domain name you bought?  Did you do a traceroute to the domain name?

Comment: If I ping the domain in Windows I get "Reply from (my ip): bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64", this would mean, that my A-record is working right?